# For loop with discrete values in R

Tags: r

I have a vector with increasing discrete values of the following form:

```
a<-c(1,2,5,7,8,9,10,15,19...)
```

I would like to run a for loop which runs through the values of a.

I have tried:

```
for (i in 1:a)
```

but this ignores that there are missing values and also looks at 3, 4, etc.

I have also tried:

```
for (i in 1:unique(a))
```

but this gives the following error:

```
In 1:unique(a) :
 numerical expression has 1350 elements: only the first used
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
for ( i in a )
```

`a` is already a vector. The `1:N` construct you usually see in `for` loops is used as short-hand to create a vector of integers from 1 to N.

Answer (score 2):

Tim pointed out the correct way to go about this.  However, based on the attempts you've made, you may also want to check out `?seq` and `?seq_along`

`1:a`  and `1:unique(a)` both take the first element in the vector `a` (or `unique(a)`) and use that as the "upper limit" in the sequence.  (so long as the first element of `a` can be coerced into an integer).

For example

```
  a <- c("7", "hello", "world")
  1:a   # same as 1:7
  # [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

  a <- c("hello", "7", "world")
  1:a   # same as 1:"hello"
  # ERROR
```

Where as if you use `seq_along(a)`, it will give you an index to each element of a. (useful if you need to use that index for some other calculation)

```
 for (i in seq_along(a))
    cat(a[[i]], "\t is the", i,"element.\n")

 # hello     is the 1 element.
 # 7         is the 2 element.
 # world     is the 3 element.
```